# Procedure to test whether list represents a set with no duplicates

Tags: list, prolog

In Prolog how do you write a procedure that can be used to test whether or not a list represents a set with no duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. @thanosQR is right in pointing to SWI-Prolog's `is_set/1`, but if you want a portable solution, you can define that predicate in terms of `setof`:

```
is_set(Lst) :-
    setof(X, member(X, Lst), Set),
    length(Lst, N),
    length(Set, N).
```

A list contains no duplicates if its number of elements is equal to the number of elements in the `setof` its elements.

You can also use the (I believe non-standard, but commonly available) `sort/2`, which eliminates duplicates:

```
is_set(Lst) :-
    sort(Lst, Set),
    length(Lst, N),
    length(Set, N).
```

This takes O(*n* lg *n*) time to run.

Answer (score 3):

We define `distinct_t/2` based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915):

```
distinct_t([], true).
distinct_t([X|Xs], T) :-
   if_(memberd_t(X,Xs), T=false, distinct_t(Xs,T)).
```

Let's start with the most general use of `distinct_t/2`:

```
?- distinct_t(Xs,T).
   T = true , Xs = []
;  T = true , Xs = [_A]
;  T = false, Xs = [_A,_A|_B]
;  T = true , Xs = [_A,_B],       dif(_B,_A)
;  T = false, Xs = [_A,_B,_A|_C], dif(_B,_A)
;  T = false, Xs = [_A,_B,_B],    dif(_B,_A), dif(_B,_A)
;  T = true , Xs = [_A,_B,_C],    dif(_B,_A), dif(_C,_A), dif(_C,_B)
...
```

Alright! How about this quite general query?

```
?- distinct_t([1,2,X,3],T).
   T = false, X = 1
;  T = false, X = 2
;  T = false, X = 3
;  T = true , dif(X,1), dif(X,2), dif(X,3).
```

If we are only interested in cases with `T = true`, we use `dictinct/1`—defined like this:

```
distinct(Xs) :-
   distinct_t(Xs, true).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- distinct([1,2,3,1]).
false.
?- distinct([1,2,3,2]).
false.
?- distinct([1,2,3,3]).
false.
?- distinct([1,2,3,4]).
true.                     % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 2):

First, define a predicate to make sure a value isn't in a list:

```
notin(A,[]).
notin(A,[B|C]) :- A\=B, notin(A,C).
```

Then, our nodups predicate makes sure each element doesn't appear in the part of the list that comes after it:

```
nodups([]).
nodups([_]).
nodups([A|B]) :- notin(A,B), nodups(B).
```

Comment: This requires O(n²) time to run. See my answer for an O(n lg n) solution. (Besides, `notin(X,Lst)` can be replaced with `\+ memberchk(X,Lst)`.)

Comment: @larsmans why `memberchk/2` instead of `member/2` in a `(\+)/1` call ? It'll stop at the first match anyway, won't it ?

Comment: @Mog: I believe `memberchk` is still more efficient; SWI-Prolog's `time/1` shows it performs fewer inferences.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sort/2`, `ground/1`, `same_length/2`, and [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915):

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

is_set(S) :-
   iwhen(ground(S), (same_length(S,T), sort(S,T))).
```

Sample uses:

```
?- is_set([4,1,3,2]).        % not in standard order
true.                        % OK: no duplicates

?- is_set([1,2,3,1,2]).
false.

?- is_set([1,2,3,1,X]).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 1):

`is_set/1`: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_set/1
(Assuming that you still want it for swi-prolog)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, some forall madness (quadratic complexity so it's worse than the `is_set/1` mentionned above, but w/e) :

```
duplicates(List) :-
    forall(select(Item, List, Rest),
           forall(member(Item2, Rest),
                  Item \== Item2)).
```