# If I ask for X, it generates duplicates, but it fails on duplicates if I ask explicitly

Tags: prolog

I am trying to generate pieces on a board at specific positions. One requirement is no two pieces can occupy the same position.
So the board as a list, cannot contain duplicate entries for it's position value.

I failed to remove the duplicates in generation part, otherwise it correctly fails on duplicates if I ask it explicitly.

```
role(k).
role(r).

color(w).
color(b).

piece(X-Y) :- color(X), role(Y).

piese(X-Y) :- piece(X), pos_(Y).

piese_pos(X, Y) :- X=_-_-Y.

board(Ps) :- maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls), is_set(Ls), maplist(piese, Ps).

pos_(a-1).
pos_(a-2).
/*
When I ask board board(X). This is one of the enumerations:
X = [w-k-(a-1), b-k-(a-2), w-r-(a-2)] ;
as you can see a-2 is duplicated.

But if I ask for a duplicate explicitly, it returns false as correct.
[11]  ?- board([w-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-1)]).
false.

[11]  ?- board([w-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)]).
true.
*/

% https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007359/3994249
is_set(Lst) :-
  setof(X, member(X, Lst), Set),
  length(Lst, N),
  length(Set, N).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every position on the board must have a piece, you can generate boards with the following code:

```
board(Ps) :-
    setof(P, pos_(P), Ls),     
    maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls),
    maplist(piese, Ps).
```

Example:

```
?- board(Ps).
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)].
```

Otherwise, you can use this other definition:

```
board(Ps) :-
    setof(P, pos_(P), S),
    set_subset(S, Ls),
    maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls),
    maplist(piese, Ps).

set_subset([], []).
set_subset([X|Xs], S) :-
    set_subset(Xs, T),
    (   S = T
    ;   S = [X|T] ).
```

Example:

```
?- board(Ps).
Ps = [] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-k-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), w-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), w-r-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), b-k-(a-2)] ;
Ps = [b-r-(a-1), b-r-(a-2)].
```

Answer (score 1):

The `board` rule appears to generate "false" solutions because no values have been bound yet when the `is_set` check takes place. When you pass in a result that has actual values, `is_set` will be false as expected. To see this happening, run only the first two conditions of `board/1`:

```
?- maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls), is_set(Ls).
Ps = [_2962-_2964-_2950],
Ls = [_2950] ;
Ps = [_2962-_2964-_2950, _4224-_4226-_4212],
Ls = [_2950, _4212] ;
Ps = [_2962-_2964-_2950, _4224-_4226-_4212, _5550-_5552-_5538],
Ls = [_2950, _4212, _5538] ;
Ps = [_2962-_2964-_2950, _4224-_4226-_4212, _5550-_5552-_5538, _6932-_6934-_6920],
Ls = [_2950, _4212, _5538, _6920] ;
...
```

While this appears to be generating the "structure" of the answer, no values are being bound yet and the `is_set` call will always succeed here on empty variable positions. Switching the order of the predicates produces the results you may be looking for but will highlight the another issue:

```
?- maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls), maplist(piese, Ps), is_set(Ls).
Ps = [w-k-(a-1)],
Ls = [a-1] ;
Ps = [w-k-(a-2)],
Ls = [a-2] ;
Ps = [w-r-(a-1)],
...
Ps = [b-r-(a-2), b-r-(a-1)],
Ls = [a-2, a-1] ;
... (no response)
```

After enumerating all expected solutions with both of the positions currently defined, it will loop endlessly as the first `maplist` will continue unbounded, generating duplicate positions in an ever growing list. Adding condition to cut the search at that point may be what you want, or a different approach first enumerating positions then placing pieces in them could be easier.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: `is_set(Ls), maplist(piese, Ps)` checks unbound variables before they have values. After that, duplicate values can get in. Do these two things the other way around.

---

The problem is shown in this trace of your code generating a board of length 2:

- At the top arrow the board must have two things in it, they are shown as variables with no human given name, and no value so they get automatic names of _840 and _846.
- At the pair of arrows, the maplist call has got the right pattern of `[A-B-C, X-Y-Z]` for the board contents, with automatic names for the variables to hold each part.
- At the last arrow, unknown variables for the positions have been stripped off and handed to is_set. Still with no values, two unground variables are a set, so they get past the check.

[image: Showing the trace of generating the board]

After that, you put values in the variables, no more checks are done.

Change:

```
board(Ps) :- maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls), is_set(Ls), maplist(piese, Ps).
```

to:

```
board(Ps) :- maplist(piese_pos, Ps, Ls), maplist(piese, Ps), is_set(Ls).
```

Then piese searches for values before is_set checks for duplicates.

Logically there may be no difference, but practically Prolog systems can't do everything at once and must do some things first and some later.

Comment: This solution loops endlessly as rayscan has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version, that is pure logical.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523825/3994249

```
board([]).
board([P]) :- pos(P).
board([_-Pos,_-Pos2]) :- pos(Pos), pos(Pos2), dif(Pos, Pos2).
board([X,Y|Rest]) :- board([X|Rest]), board([Y|Rest]), board([X,Y]).
```